Token hidden by Phantom Wallet
Hi Guys a bought a token called Fiji, CA A9e6JzPQstmz94pMnzxgyV14QUqoULSXuf5FPsq8UiRa
My Phantom wallet hid it instantly, and next to it when i go into the manage token list, it has a yellow triangle iwth exclamation mark next to it.
Stupdily, I also realise the token is called fiji.exe, and the twitter profile actually says about it being 'AI Peace Virus Trojan Malware' in the title.
Has anyone heard of this project, or have any reccomendations as to what I should do, please?
Many thanks for any info.
